# Mysql autorepair

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I need MySQL to auto repair on damage. I have found that I can check and repair MySQL tables manually. Is there an option to make it repairing it self when ever needed automatically. Without explicit external effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run several MySQL operations via cron jobs, so I suppose you could schedule a MySQL check periodically the same way. You may want to have a deeper look on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html) for the differences between the checks/repairs operations.

I don't know any other "magical" solution.

Answer (score 0):

It generally happens if you have innodb tables  and and suddenly your database shut down.
do you run mysqlcheck database table? generally this command will recover your table. If it dont solve your problem you can log in your database and could run the following command to rebuild your index

alter table table_name engine=InnoDB;